# I want to know if I can import the testcase from documents,such as .xls or .csv

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I want to know if I can import the testcases from documents,such as .xls or .csv

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIKTQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/import-export/

You can't by default:

> Kiwi TCMS does not and will not support import and export
> functionality to/from Excel, XML, CSV or other formats!

Edit: because there's no way for the system to know what your data represents

> When importing historical test data from other systems your input files may > contain arbitrary information, whose organization and meaning is known only > to you! There’s no way Kiwi TCMS will be able to reliably guess what that
> data may be and how to interpret it.
> You can create your own importer:
> Kiwi TCMS however provides a very powerful API. The same API is used
> by our front-end interface via JavaScript! Using this API you can
> create a script which will parse your input files, possibly reorganize
> them and send the information to Kiwi TCMS. This gives you the
> ultimate control over how to import and export data to/from Kiwi TCMS!

Comment: Cool！thank you very much！

Comment: Editted answer with clarification why automatic import doesn't make sense in most cases.